# Generar procesos almacenados o funciones en mongodb V.4.2 y Ejecutarlo en php

Tags: mongodb, stored-procedure

He intentado ejecutar funciones generadas en mongoDB, desde mi aplicación creada en PHP, pero no he tenido exito en versiones anteriores de mongo lo generaba de la siguiente manera.
$resultado = $mongoConection->execute("mifuncion('".$parametro."')");

pero para la version 4.2 de mongodb, execute es obsoleto,espero me puedan apoyar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [`eval()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) está marcado como obsoleto desde la [versión 3.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-eval-command). El método [`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mongodb.execute.php) del driver de PHP para MongoDB se basa en este comando.

**¿Qué alternativas existen?**

Pues la verdad ninguna que yo recomiende, y es por una razón específica: evitar la carga adicional en el motor de base de datos al ejecutar código de Javascript.

No tiene sentido práctico delegar lógica de aplicación a la base de datos. Y aunque muchos opinen que puede ser más eficiente procesar grandes cantidades de datos en el motor de Base de Datos, lo cual hasta cierto punto puede ser correcto, eso crea una dependencia de la lógica almacenada en dicha Base de Datos.

**Sí, hay una alternativa.**

Sin embargo no todo es malo, y en MongoDB podemos [declarar funciones de Javascript y almacenarlas](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) en una [colección del sistema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/index.html) llamada [`system.js`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/index.html#%3Cdatabase%3E.system.js)

Para almacenar una función en esta colección usaremos el método [`insertOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#db.collection.insertOne).

Por ejemplo, supongamos que almacenaré la siguiente función:

```js
const promedio = function(values) {
  let suma = values.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
  return suma / values.length;
}
```

Es una función que me permite calcular el promedio de ciertos valores.

Para guardar dicha función y usarla (en un contexto de Javascript, como [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) o [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)), debo hacer lo siguiente:

```js
db.system.js.insertOne({
  _id: 'promedio',
  value: promedio
});
```

Ahora supongamos que deseo aplicar dicha función para devolver la lista de alumnos que obtuvieron un promedio de notas igual o superior a un valor dado.

Nuestros documentos:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId('5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155ad7'),
  alumno: ObjectId('5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155ad1'),
  notas: [5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 5]
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155ac7'),
  alumno: ObjectId('5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155ac1'),
  notas: [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 3]
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155aa7'),
  alumno: ObjectId('5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155aa1'),
  notas: [7, 8, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9]
}
```

Ahora podemos usar nuestra función almacenada en una consulta como la siguiente:

```js
db.notas.find({$where: 'promedio(this.notas) >= 5'});
```

En esta consulta estoy usando directamente la función `promedio`, a la cual le estoy pasando como argumento la lista de notas de cada documento de la colección notas.

El resultado de dicha consulta sobre mi colección de notas se vería así:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155ad7"), "alumno" : ObjectId("5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155ad1"), "notas" : [ 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155aa7"), "alumno" : ObjectId("5f3c3c8c945bec6f1e155aa1"), "notas" : [ 7, 8, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9 ] }
```

Entonces ya tengo una forma de consultar los alumnos que tienen un promedio de nota igual o superior a 5.

**¿Cómo lo uso en PHP (o cualquier otro driver)?**

Muy sencillo, aunque debo aclarar que por razones de seguridad la inserción de funciones en la colección del sistema debería realizarse/permitirse únicamente desde la consola de MongoDB y no desde un cliente web.

Supongamos que deseo usar la misma función desde una consulta en PHP, pues sería parecida a la siguiente:

```php
$query = array('$where' => 'promedio(this.notas) >= 5');

$notas = $notasCollection->find($query);

foreach ($notas as $nota) {
    var_dump($nota['notas']);
}
```

Como se aprecia, estoy usando el operador [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html) dentro el `Array` llamado `$query`. A dicho operador le estoy asignando el nombre de la función almacenada en la Base de Datos (`promedio`), y a la misma le paso como argumento `this.notas`, ya que cada documento a ser procesado se referencia con `this`.

El resultado de dicha consulta es el siguiente:

```php
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#12 (1) { 
  ["storage": "ArrayObject":private] => array(7) {
    [0]=> float(5) [1]=> float(6) [2]=> float(4) [3]=> float(7) [4]=> float(8) [5]=> float(9) [6]=> float(5) 
  }
}
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#16 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(7) {
    [0]=> float(7) [1]=> float(8) [2]=> float(6) [3]=> float(8) [4]=> float(8) [5]=> float(9) [6]=> float(9)
  }
}
```

Esta es una alternativa al uso del método obsoleto `execute()` y que ya no está disponible para versiones de MongoDB 4.2 o superiores.